# Get version of wxWidgets in CMake

Tags: cmake, wxwidgets

I am trying to determine if the version of wxWidgets found by CMake is >= 2.9. I tried this:

```
find_package(wxWidgets 2.9 COMPONENTS core base REQUIRED)
if(wxWidgets_FOUND)
  message("wxWidgets found successfully.")
  include( ${wxWidgets_USE_FILE} )
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "wxWidgets was not found!")
endif()

if(wxWidgets_VERSION LESS 2.9)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "wxWidgets is not a high enough version!")
else()
  message("wxWidgets Version ${wxWidgets_VERSION}")
  message("wxWidgets Major version ${wxMAJOR_VERSION}")
  message("release number ${wxRELEASE_NUMBER}")
  message("check version ${wxCHECK_VERSION}")
  message("wxWidgets version ${WX_WIDGETS_VERSION}")
  message("wxWidgets major version ${WX_MAJOR_VERSION}")
  message("wxWidgets version string ${WX_VERSION_STRING}")
endif()
```

(My system has wx2.8, so this should fail).

The if(wxWidgets_FOUND) returns TRUE, so so far so good. However, the if(wxWidgets_VERSION LESS 2.9) fails, but it is not because wxWidgets_VERSION is < 2.9. It is because wxWidgets_VERSION is empty. In fact, the whole output is:

```
wxWidgets Version 
wxWidgets Major version 
release number 
check version 
wxWidgets version 
wxWidgets major version 
wxWidgets version string
```

(i.e. all of the variables are empty)

Does anyone know the correct way to check for the wxWidgets version through CMake?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Check you FindWxWidgets.cmake module. I don't know exactly which one you are using but, for example, in [this](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/FindWxWin.Cmake) wxversion is defined only for Windows(and I guess not the way you will like it)  and in [this](http://code.google.com/p/vtp/source/browse/trunk/CMakeModules/FindwxWidgets.cmake?r=7130) one version isn't defined.

Comment: I think the provided find scripts for wx are not really well maintained. So maybe you'll have to modify one for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone suggested a project named wxArt2d that has a bit better wxWidgets cmake. It is unfortunate that these things are not easier/better maintained :(

Answer (score 3):

On my Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
CMake command:

```
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)
```

calls macro:

```
/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake
```

which sets following variables:

```
wxWidgets_VERSION_STRING   # 3.0.4
wxWidgets_VERSION_MAJOR    # 3
wxWidgets_VERSION_MINOR    # 0
wxWidgets_VERSION_PATCH    # 4
```

So following code checks the version:

```
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})

if (wxWidgets_VERSION_STRING LESS 2.9)
    message("Version < 2.9")
endif()

# Or
if (wxWidgets_VERSION_STRING GREATER_EQUAL 2.9)
    message("Version >= 2.9")
endif()
```

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal and write

```
wx-config --version
```

Comment: How does this help with getting the version in CMake?